# Get AST of dart source code

Tags: dart, interpreter

I was thinking about writing a dart interpreter in dart.

As the dart to javascript compiler is written in dart, is it possible to use it to get the AST from dart source code?

How can I do that and would this approach work in the browser?

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/analyzer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and this is roughly what try.dartlang.org does. I say roughly, because it doesn't interpret it, it runs the whole dart2js compiler in the browser.

So you could do this, get the AST and interpret that. You could also use the Analyzer package to get the AST instead. The analyzer's representation has tended to be more stable than the dart2js internal one, and is easier to rely on because you can just depend on a package rather than the internals of the SDK. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/analyzer

Comment: I don't suppose you have any examples of using the `analyzer` package to parse an arbitrary source file into an AST?  I found some ~6 year old ones that don't seem to compile anymore.